# Combine IF with AND/OR python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

Im trying to filter out some "words/characters" out of an python string.
Here is my code:

```
if "MV" not in network_name:
    if "MOB" not in network_name:
        if "MG" not in network_name:
            if "RO" not in network_name:
                if "RQ" not in network_name:
                    if "RM" not in network_name:
                        if "RT" not in network_name:
                            if "RC" not in network_name:
                                if "RW" not in network_name:
                                    if "RU" not in network_name:
                                        if "RA" not in network_name:
                                            if "RH" not in network_name:
                                                print ('OK')
```

Is there an way to make an oneliner with all of the filters?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One option: `sum([1 if word in network_name else 0 for word in words]) == 0` where `words` is the list of undesirable words (`words = ["MV", "MOB", "MG", ...]`).

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to use set or any operation

example

```
if not any(1 if i in network for i in ['MV', 'MOB', 'NG']): 
    print('ok')
```

or

```
 if len(set(['MV','MOB']).intersection(set(network)))==0:
        print('ok')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code using the `any` operator:

```
s = "AF GV BH TF"
l1 = ["AF", "GB"]
l2 = ["VG, FT"]
print(any(i in s for i in l1))  #True, since AF is in string s
print(any(i in s for i in l2))  #False
```

You can similarly add the substrings to check in a list and use the `any` operator as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a set of all your desired strings as `set1` for example

```
if bool(set1.symmetric_difference(network_name)):
    print("OK")
```